# Codeigniter : Getting Select option value from name[]

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

wish to modified an existing system, which added the UOM dropdown select field.
i would like to get my selected value to my CodeIgnitor controller, but it seems not working.

```
    <tbody id="dataTable" style="background: #cccccc ">
<tr>    
    <!--<td><input type = "checkbox" name="chkbox[]"/></td>-->
    <td></td>
    <td><input required type="text" name="item[]"/></td>
    <td><input required type="text"  name="price[]" /></td>
    <td><input required type="text"  name="qty[]" /></td>
    <td><select required type="text" name="uom[]">
        <option value = "">--Please Select--</option>
        <option value = "PCS">PCS - Pieces</option>
        <option value = "M">M - Meters</option>
        <option value = "KG">KG - Kilograms</option>
        <option value = "BOX">BOX - Boxes</option>
        <option value = "SET">SET - Sets</option>
        <option value = "CTN">CTN - Cartons</option>
        <option value = "PLT">PLT - Pallets</option>
        <option value = "ROLL">ROLL - Rolls</option>
        <option value = "PKT">PKT - Packets</option>
        </select>
    </td>  
</tr>
```

Below are my controller:

```
public function user_data_submit() {

    $data = array(
        //'tranh_item_uom' is my uom database's column
        'tranh_item_uom'=>$this->input->post('uom1'),
        'tranh_item_uom2'=>$this->input->post('uom2'),
        'tranh_item_uom3'=>$this->input->post('uom3'),
        'tranh_item_uom4'=>$this->input->post('uom4'),
        'tranh_item_uom5'=>$this->input->post('uom5'),
    );


}
```

Not luck of getting it the uom[] to work. Sorry that i just pick up codeignitor and php recently , still not very familiar with it.

My complete code here:

- Controller.php -> https://codepen.io/Kezn/pen/QWWQywb
- Viewer.php -> https://codepen.io/Kezn/pen/WNNMrvv

Answer (score 0):

To get all of the `uom[]` input, you could compose the `$data` array like this :

```php
public function user_data_submit() {

    $uoms = $this->input->post('uom');
    $data = [];
    foreach ($uoms as $key => $value) {
        reset($uoms);
        $i = $key;
        if ($key === key($uoms)) {
            $i = ''; // set first array item key as empty
        }
        $data[$key] = [
            "tranh_item_uom$i" => $value
        ];
    }


}
```